# wowza wemcam recording with flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, wowza

Hi guys have any suggestions  solutions for recording video from webcam and storing it on the wowza media server? with flash and actionscript I tried the wowza recording example but I couldn't figure out Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

main point is to modify Application.xml, so StreamType will contain "-record", like "live-record".
more about it here:
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-wowza-streaming-engine#streamTypes

you can also look here (HTTPLiveStreamRecord):
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-record-live-streams-httplivestreamrecord
here's also an article to do recording programmatically:
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-start-and-stop-live-stream-recordings-programmatically-imediastreamactionnotify3

Answer (score 0):

I developed a flash-webcam-encoder which you can use with wowza : [https://github.com/crsepulv/webcam-flash-rtmp-h264[1](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-record-live-streams-httplivestreamrecord)

you install it on your webser server, set your specific wowza params and it will strart streaming your webcam to wowza.

on Wowza Manager you go to Incoming streams and you will find the webcam streaming and click Record and it will strart recording.

if you want to automate the process you could use the Wowza Livestreamrecord  API,  you could find it here

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-record-live-streams-httplivestreamrecord